# How can I update table cells to an editable field on a selection?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, onclick

I have a Table and I want some table-cells to change to a selection, where the user can change the values.

So far it works, but if I click on the `<td>`-cell, the text value changes to my selection. But when I try to click on the selection to chose a new value, my option-list just shows for a second.

I figured out, that if I click on my selection, the function runs again and changes the value of the `td-cell` to my selection, so I am not able to change it.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(".editTable.tdInactive").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("WOAS?");
  var $ = jQuery;
  var this_object = $(this);

  this_object.removeClass('tdInactive');
  this_object.addClass('tdActive');

  var current_content = $(this).html();

  var new_content = $(this).attr('data-select');

  this_object.empty();
  this_object.append(new_content);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-select="MY SELECTION CODE" class="editTable tdInactive">VALUE AS TEXT TO CHANGE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do the click function on a span inside the td <span>VALUE AS TEXT TO CHANGE</span>. On click replace the span with the select, then on save select data put the span back with the new selection

Comment: Thx this works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( ".editTable.tdInactive" ).on( "click", function( event ){
event.preventDefault();
alert("WOAS?");

var this_object = $( this );

this_object.removeClass('tdInactive');
this_object.addClass('tdActive');

var current_content = $(this).html();

var new_content = $(this).data('select');


this_object.empty();
this_object.html( new_content );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
<tr>
<td data-select="MY SELECTION CODE" class="editTable tdInactive">VALUE AS TEXT TO CHANGE</td>
</tr>
</table>

<style>
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Here you go.You need to take the data value like this.